# How to implement pixel art lighting as in the game Project Eastward?

Tags: unity, 2d, 3d, lighting, pixel-art

[Project Eastward Lighting Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFozVECBrMs)

[image: Lighting example 1]
[image: Lighting example 2]

Can somebody point me to the right direction as to how this lighting is done to recreate this lighting effect?

The game is 2D but uses a 3D lighting system.

Comment: How do you know it's 2d? It could very well be 3d with pixel-art textures.

Comment: The developers mentioned that in their website Pixpil Games. It's a 2D game with 3D lighting system.

Comment: Do you have a link? When you have any information about this system which could help us with research, please share it.

Comment: Yes I do have. You can see how they setup their game from scratch in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QW0fajFX3EQ .  also you can see the game engine where they have setup the lighting and the world here https://ibb.co/m4WVrb0

Comment: It doesn't seem like we can get any more useful information out of you regarding what you *actually* want, so I am going to write a more general answer about 2d lighting in Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unity Lightweight Render Pipeline recently got a couple neat additions for 2d lighting. Among them are:

- Normal mapping on 2d sprites, which can give objects a 3d impression with moving light sources
- HDR bloom
- 2d realtime shadows
- Lit areas in arbitrary shapes, either defined by polygons ("Freeform Light") or by textures ("Sprite Light")

Keep in mind that all of these features are only available in a project using the Universal Render Pipeline, not in build-in or HDRP.

A quick walkthrough of all the features is in [this video by Unity Technologies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5l8vP90EvU). Detailed information on this subject can be found [in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@11.0/manual/Lights-2D-intro.html).

One thing it can not do (AFAIK) which seems to happen in the video posted in the question is some pseudo-3d displacement of lit areas. But that displacement seems to be pretty inconsistent in that demo video, so that might not be too much of a drawback.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this asset from Asset Store [Disclamair: I am *NOT* affinity of it's author]:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/smart-lighting-2d-112535